# Change asp.net mvc bundles fingerprinting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, system.web.optimization

Is there a possibility how to change the way how System.Web.Optimization renders bundles?

From:

```
<script src="/bundles/js/bundlename?v=GMFuN8gzKMcwk5BwaMfgjUlieAXKThyQd8twrVplJ8A1"></script>
```

To something custom like this:

```
<script src="/bundles/js/v-GMFuN8gzKMcwk5BwaMfgjUlieAXKThyQd8twrVplJ8A1/bundlename"></script>
```

> UPDATE: Not ideal but small nasty workaround:

```
public static class BundlesHelper
{
        public static IHtmlString RenderScripts(params string[] paths)
        {
            #if DEBUG
            return System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render(paths);
            #endif

            // Get raw string
            var rawString = System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render(paths).ToHtmlString();

            // Get version value
            var version = Regex.Match(rawString, @"\?v=([0-9a-zA-Z_-])+").Value;

            // Remove old hash
            rawString = rawString.Replace(version, "");

            // Remove script end tag
            rawString = rawString.Replace("</script>", "");

            // Get last index of "/"
            var index = rawString.LastIndexOf('/');

            // Return new string
            return new HtmlString(rawString.Insert(index, "/v-" + version.Replace("?v=", "")) + "</script>");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That's not the point. The query string portion is a cache buster. The file is located where the script src says it is, and that doesn't change. In your desired version the actual physical location of the file would have to change.

Comment: Yes you're right. But I wanna change the location via Rewrite Rule, so I'm still looking for way how to change how fingerprint will looks like.

Comment: It's not possible without some sort of *very* hacky and ugly solution, and there's no functional benefit to doing so. Why does it even matter?

Comment: Because some of SEO testings tools doesn't like those query strings, and we're using solution for static files fingerpriting based on this  solution http://madskristensen.net/post/cache-busting-in-aspnet, so it would be nice to have homogenous solution across the project.

Comment: Mads actually says in the comments of the linked article that there's no support for this with MVC bundling. There's probably a way to tie-in the functionality, but that's sort of on you. It's far beyond the scope of a StackOverflow answer to build such a thing for you, and honestly, if you need it that bad, but can't tackle it yourself, perhaps that's a sign that this is not the best path to go down.

Comment: I see. I did some research about this theme, and unfortunately I did't find the promising way to achieve this. So stackoverflow question is just about to getting know if somebody else was facing the same situation and what was his approach. Of course I'm not expecting code-paste answer. Anyway thank you your interest.

Comment: No problem. I learned something new. Had no idea this was even a thing, but Mads gives some weight to the idea. However, even after reading the article and the comments, I still really don't see a compelling reason for ever doing this, aside from certain tools may incompetently stumble over the query string version. That's really more cause to file a bug with the tool developer than totally change how your applications work, though, in my humble opinion.